# How to fetch a collection of children applying filters on both parent and children

Tags: c#, nhibernate, list, lambda

I am using nHibernate to retrieve a collection of orders (and its order lines) from a Sql Server database.

This is my **ShipmentOrder** class:

```
public class ShipmentOrder
{
        private ICollection<ShipmentDetail> _ShipmentsDetails;

        public virtual ReadOnlyCollection<ShipmentDetail> ShipmentsDetails
        {
            get { return (new List<ShipmentDetail>(_ShipmentsDetails).AsReadOnly()); }
        }   
}
```

nHibernate returns a IList with all the details (ShipmentsDetails) loaded (since I Eager load them).

Now, I would like to filter my collection of ShipmentOrder and ShipmentDetail and get back a collection of ShipmentDetail.

I've tried something like this:

```
IList<ShipmentOrder> Results;

// Fetch orders using nHibernate
Results = FetchOrders();

var shipmentLines = Results
    .Where(x => x.Company == "XXX" && x.OrderNumber == "111")
    .SelectMany(x => x.ShipmentsDetails)
    .Where(s => s.RowNumber == 1 && s.RowSeq == 0)
    .ToList();
```

But I've realized that I obtain multiple results of the same line.

I've converted the lamda expression like this:

```
var shipmentLines = Results
    .Where(x => x.Company == "XXX" && x.OrderNumber == "111")
    .SelectMany(x => x.ShipmentsDetails)
    .Where(s => s.RowNumber == 1 && s.RowSeq == 0)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

and it works fine. 
I was wondering if there's a better way to achieve the same result without the **distinct**.

**UPDATE**:

I am using SelectMany here cause this is the only way I've found to apply filters to children (ShipmentsDetails).

Comment: Yo want to get a distinct  list without using `Distinct`?

Comment: @Jamiec: Well, the sample code I've included should return one row but I get 4 rows cause there are 4 orders. I am using SelectMany cause that's the only way I've found to applying filters on a children collection.

Comment: Does `x => x.Company == "XXX" && x.OrderNumber == "111"` identify a single `ShipmentOrder`? if so does `s.RowNumber == 1 && s.RowSeq == 0` identify a single `ShipmentLine`? What is your expected result from this query?

Comment: this looks like Linq2Objects, therefor the IList Results contains duplicate records, probably you do eager fetching to levels deep which unfortunatly results in duplicate root entities. use distinctrootentity-resulttransformer in the query

Comment: @Firo: you were absolutely right. I didn't think about that. Great. If you open an answer I'll close yours.

Comment: @Jamiec: thanks for your help. I didn't check the result from the query. The problem was there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like Linq2Objects, therefor the IList Results contains duplicate records, probably you do eager fetching to levels deep which unfortunatly results in duplicate root entities. use distinctrootentity-resulttransformer in the query